# I'm trying to toggle the screen from regular to full screen but it freezes toggling back to regular screen

Tags: python, python-3.x, visual-studio-code, pygame

Like the title said I'm trying to toggle from the normal screen to full screen and back but it like to freeze that tells me I'm doing something wrong or not understanding something.

```
window_width = 800
window_height = 600
black = (0,0,0)
close_program = False
fullscreen = False
import pygame
from pygame.constants import FULLSCREEN 
pygame.init()
from configuration import *

#pygame.display.set_caption("game name")
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((window_width, window_height),0 ,32)

while close_program == False:
    evnt = pygame.event.poll()
    if evnt.type == pygame.QUIT:
        close_program = True
    if pygame.key.get_pressed()[pygame.K_F5]:
        fullscreen = not fullscreen
    if fullscreen:
        screen = pygame.display.set_mode((window_width, window_height), pygame.FULLSCREEN, 32)
    else:
        screen = pygame.display.set_mode((window_width, window_height),0 ,32)
```

Comment: Why do you not use [`pygame.display.toggle_fullscreen()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/display.html#pygame.display.toggle_fullscreen)?

Comment: I tried it and it crashed the program. only reason why which goes back into I believe there is something I'm not understanding

Comment: You should not be repeatedly calling `set_mode`. Only do that when a corresponding event was sent.

Comment: you have an example, sorry i don't understand I believed that was the only way to set the screen

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are multiple issues with your code. The biggest is that you should only switch the fullscreen when an even came. You should in general have a main loop and inside it a `for` loop over all new events:

```
while close_program == False:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT or (event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN and event.key == pygame.K_ESCAPE):
            close_program = True
        elif event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN and event.key == pygame.K_F5:
            fullscreen = not fullscreen
            pygame.display.toggle_fullscreen()

    screen.fill(255)
    pygame.display.update()
```

That code also checks when the `F5` button was pressed, then changes the state of the `fullscreen` variable (not really needed here) and calls `pygame.display.toggle_fullscreen()`. That is how you should be switching to fullscreen.

If `toggle_fullscreen` doesn't work, you can try to do it manually:

```
        elif event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN and event.key == pygame.K_F5:
            fullscreen = not fullscreen
            if fullscreen:
                screen = pygame.display.set_mode((window_width, window_height), pygame.FULLSCREEN, 32)
            else:
                screen = pygame.display.set_mode((window_width, window_height), 0, 32)
```

That is however less ideal and doesn't work correctly for me.

Comment: I got the first one to work only question I have is that is it suppose to minimize all other programs too?

Comment: @DemetriusAlize It doesn't for me. Might be OS dependent. It changes the display resolution on windows for example, maybe that is the effect you are observing?